# REGEXP_LIKE is not working properly with CASE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use REGEXP_LIKE in a CASE statement (In an ORACLE DB).
When I use it only once it is working OK:

```
case when  regexp_like(CURRENT_OPER, MDT_CONFIG_OPER) > 0 then 1 end
```

when I add a 2nd REGEXP_LIKE - I get an error

> The SQL statement is not supported.

```
case when regexp_like(CURRENT_OPER, MDT_CONFIG_OPER) > 0
      and regexp_like(NEXT_OPER, MDT_CONFIG_OPER) > 0 
     then 1
end
```

Any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact reason why Oracle chokes on the second version.  But `REGEXP_LIKE` returns a boolean and so comparing to zero is not necessary.  The following version should work:

```sql
CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(CURRENT_OPER, MDT_CONFIG_OPER) AND 
          REGEXP_LIKE(NEXT_OPER, MDT_CONFIG_OPER) THEN 1 END
```